# Spring Boot JPA get reference to EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot

I have a Spring-Boot web application, and I have a 3rd party jar that has a data access layer.  In order to use it,  I have to send it a reference to an EntityManagerFactory.  I am able to do this like this:

```
    Map<String, String> stg = new HashMap<String, String>();
    stg.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb");
    stg.put("hibernate.connection.username", "name");
    stg.put("hibernate.connection.password", "password");

    EntityManagerFactory fact = MultipleEntityManagerFactoryHolder.getEmf("stg", stg);
```

But how do I get the one that Spring (I assume)  has already built for me when I add this to the application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
```

I have no access to the jar,  so I need the factory,  not the DataSource.  Anyone know how to get that?

Comment: do I understand your question right?  You want to add the properties to your Map using the entity manager build on the entries of your property file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply autowire it in your bean:

```
@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory emFactory;
```

Comment: I really need to remember that most of what I need is already there in Spring Boot.  thanks!